# How can I search a column for any value and move the row to another sheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

The objective I'm trying to achieve is to compare all the values in a column and if the value is NOT blank, move the entire row to another sheet, and delete the row from the first sheet. I'm very novice at this, and I know that my code is incomplete to accomplish the objective, but so far this is what I have:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const row = event.range.getRow();
  const col = event.range.getColumn();
  const as = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  const numColumns = as.getLastColumn();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

  if(as.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && as.getRange(row,19) == "") {

   as.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
   //as.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Form Responses 1" && sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 19).getValue() != "") {
    const tsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    const trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg);
  }
}
```

Then you probably can't delete either

Comment: I get an error saying, "Exception: Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead" Any help?